# Getting wrong answer Using Thread safe counter

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, pthreads, counter

I am counting a counter till 1000000 , 50 times Using 2 threads. I am using lock , but I am getting different answer every time. Why it is happening so.
I thought I will get the counter value exactly 1000000 , but it is not behaving that way. What may be the reason?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#define OPERATIONS 50
long unsigned int counter1=0;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

pthread_t tid[2];


void* myOperation()
{   
    while(counter1<1000000) {
        int pi=pthread_self();
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
        ++counter1;
        //printf("\n counter: %lu thread %d\n", counter1,pi);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    }
    return NULL;  
}

int main()
{
    int k = 0,p=0;;
    int err;

    int t=0;
    int i, j;
    i=0;


    for(j = 0; j < OPERATIONS; j++) {       
        counter1=0;
        k=0;

        while(k < 2) {
            err = pthread_create(&(tid[k]), NULL, &myOperation, NULL);
            if (err != 0)
                printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
            k++;
        }
        pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);

        printf("iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- %lu\n",counter1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000001
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000001
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000001
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000001
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000001
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
iiiiiiiiiiiii ----- 1000000
```

Comment: Do you ever initialise & declare  `counter1`? If so, where?

Comment: @Magisch By mistake I didn't copy the upper part of file. Added

Comment: `pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);` Take a guess at what that does? Clue: once you destroy something you generally can't use it anymore. And you certainly are using the lock after that.

Comment: Add to that, any particular  reason you're using `sem_init` for initializing a pthread *mutex* ? Whatever text you're using for your pthread tutorial, burn it and get another. [`pthread_mutex_init`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_init.html) and/or `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` should be used instead.

Comment: @kaylum I got it . I corrected that . But still I am getting same answer

Comment: What is the variable `mutex` declared to be? It's not shown. Are you making this up as you go or is this your real code?

Comment: that is not the good way to do multi-threadings. it doesn't make sense what you are doing. also pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock); should be at the end of all operations.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry for the typos in the code, I am not using sem_init for initializing pthread mutex;   edited the code

Comment: @Tarun Please, you need to show the real code that you have compiled and run. Otherwise you will cause a lot of churn and wasted comments.

Comment: Sorry guys,  I will be more careful from next time.

Comment: Another nice example why one should **always** check the outcome of **all** relevant function calls. *All* those `pthread_*()` functions return an error code. The code you show mostly ignores it. Why? Those are debugging helpers for *free*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems.  Firstly, you aren't initialising your mutex.  You have a static mutex so you can use the static initialiser:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Secondly, you shouldn't be calling `pthread_mutex_destroy()` in the loop - that's only supposed to be called when you will never use the mutex again.  In this case, with a static mutex, you don't need to call `pthread_mutex_destroy()` at all - it will be cleaned up at program exit.

The third problem is that you read `counter1` without holding the lock.  One example of how this can go wrong is that both threads can read `counter1` at the same time and see the value 999999 - they will both decide to increment it, so it will end up at 1000001.  You need to hold the lock continuously between deciding to increment the counter and actually incrementing it.  Something like:

```
void* myOperation()
{
    int finished = 0;

    while (!finished) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if (counter1 < 1000000)
            ++counter1;
        else
            finished = 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
```